# AngularJS code does not work after a change in HTTP GET URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http, cakephp

I have an angularjs code that uses $http to call a HTTP GET request.

```
$http.get(url_get).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
}
```

It works fine. The URL looks something like this;

http://127.0.0.1/echo/monthly/get_report?start_date=2015-01-00&end_date=2015-09-00

The REST API server was implemented in cakephp. The AngularJS code resides under the webroot folder.

I reimplemented the cakephp REST API server in node.js but this time using a different port. The new URL looks like this;

http://127.0.0.1:7898/echo/monthly/get_report?start_date=2015-01-00&end_date=2015-09-00

However, the same angularjs code stops working with the node.js REST API server. The error was

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://127.0.0.1:7898/echo/monthly/get_report?start_date=2015-01-00&end_date=2015-09-00.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 405.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Make the response to the preflight request properly pass access control check by adding the said missing header. The error message tells you both what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: What's wrong with the question? Why downvote?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. This is the most common error that gets posted here on SO related to ajax requests. Look at the list over there >>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use cors Library

CORS is a node.js package for providing a Connect/Express middleware that can be used to enable CORS with various options.

[go to npm cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

#### Simple Usage (Enable *All* CORS Requests)

```
var express = require('express')
     , cors = require('cors')
     , app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/products/:id', function(req, res, next){
   res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'});
});

app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
});
```

#### Enable CORS for a Single Route

```
var express = require('express')
     , cors = require('cors')
     , app = express();

 app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function(req, res, next){
     res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'});
 });

 app.listen(80, function(){
     console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
 });
```

Comment: Does anything need to be done on the Angularjs client side? I am using restify and enabled CORS. I still get the same error. Wondering if extra stuff needs to be done at client side.

Comment: It is working now. I am using restify. No change needed in Angularjs. Thanks.